# How to get the number of instructions executed inside a virtual machine from the host?

Tags: qemu, kvm, perf, intel-pmu

I have attempted to use the `perf kvm stat -p vmpid` command to get the number of instructions executed.

However, I have observed that the command still reports a significant number of instructions even in the VM guest kernel crash state (instruction expects to approach 0). Just like:

```
          3,835.91 msec task-clock:G              #    1.000 CPUs utilized
                25      context-switches:G        #    0.007 K/sec
                 7      cpu-migrations:G          #    0.002 K/sec
                 0      page-faults:G             #    0.000 K/sec
    10,879,172,713      cycles:G                  #    2.836 GHz
       905,371,317      instructions:G            #    0.08  insn per cycle
       150,903,724      branches:G                #   39.340 M/sec
            23,387      branch-misses:G           #    0.02% of all branches
```

Is there an alternative method to exclusively capture the count of instructions executed internally by the VM?

My virtual machine is based on the qemu/kvm platform.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to accurately measure the executed instructions within the VM from the host side.

PS: The guest kernel crash was manually triggered by me, and the command is
`echo c >  /proc/sysrq-trigger`

Comment: Are interrupts are disabled in the crashed VM?  If not, perhaps that's how instructions are executing.  What do you mean "crashed", anyway?  Not sending responses to network packets doesn't mean the CPU core(s) are all in deep sleep.  The VM could be running network driver code to receive packets but perhaps user-space is stuck, or if not responding even to pings, maybe something in the kernel is in a bad state, but that doesn't trigger a power-saving sleep.

Comment: The guest kernel crash was manually triggered by me, and the command is as follows. I will add it to the problem description.
`echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

Comment: Ok, so a Linux kernel.  Have you checked what sysrq Crash is supposed to do?  Or used a debugger to see what's happening on the CPU(s) inside the VM?  (Or used a debugger to see what's happening on the CPU(s) after doing this in an emulator like Bochs or QEMU?  QEMU can act as a remote for GDB, so you can easily attach to a single-core guest and single-step its CPU to see what's happening.)